# Can not understand this DOM target with JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to target these elements:

```
<audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
```

So I'm trying to use this code to play them:

```
 window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
 const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');

 console.log(audio);
 if(!audio) return; // stop function
 audio.play();
 });
```

How ever, when pressing A, the data key returns Null. This is what the console says:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "a", code: "KeyA", location: 0, 
ctrlKey: false, …}
index-START.html:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null
at index-START.html:65
```

So I get I doesn't work, because it's Null. But I don't understand why its Null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You need to use the string interpolation symbols ( ` ) around that string in order to do the ${...} substitution properly:

```
`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`
```

Otherwise the selector query is receiving the literal string which is trying to match elements with data-key equal to `"${e.keyCode}"`.  This is called a "template literal" and you can read more about the nuances [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Alternatively, you could do this to avoid using a template literal and stick to standard quotes:

```
'audio[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]'
```

Comment: Works now, thanks! I'll stick to standard quotes next time!

Comment: That's a good idea if you want to support IE browsers.  We only template literals on the server (node.js) where we can control the JavaScript version we use.

Answer (score 2):

you made a small mistake in your query selector, your not using literal strings.

' should be `

```
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```